# Trivial but CPU consumptive task in Python uses less than half the CPU in Windows only

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying to debug a performance issue between the same Python 3 program on Windows, and on Unix or OS/X.

While I'm not sure this is the root of the issue, I note that if I execute `sum(range(100000000))` on an otherwise idle OS/X or Ubuntu machine, I use all (95%+) of one core.  When this is executed on on an otherwise idle Windows 10, it uses only about 35% of one core.

Why is this so?

Comment: Well, that depends where you're getting these measurements from, precisely.

Comment: windows is better than *nix ?

Comment: Task Manager in Windows, `top`/Activity Monitor on OS/X, `top` on Linux.  However, the difference is so gross (3x!) that it really isn't clear to me that the measuring tool could possibly make a difference.

Comment: "windows is better than *nix?" 

No, windows is performing much worse than *nix in this example.  It's taking about three times as long to do the same computation because it's only using a third of the CPU at its disposal.

Comment: @TomSwirly: Are you sure it's using 35% of one core? Checking the Details view in Task Manager, I reliably fill a whole core, which on my machine (4 cores) shows as 25% (because Windows reports a percentage of total CPU available, not percent of one core). I'm wondering if maybe you're running on a 3-core CPU. Also, side-note: Are you sure you're running Python 3 on all systems? Python 2's `range` would generate a huge `list` of `int` which would likely cause page file thrashing, and could reduce CPU utilization.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I am totally sure that we're running Python 3.5 on both tests.  In fact, my first test tried deliberately to thrash memory with `list(range())` Now, I'm not the Windows engineer.  I have his trouble report and it says 4 cores BUT now that I know that Task Manager reports percentage of total CPU including all cores, I'm thinking that 35% of *total* CPU isn't really unreasonable.  Checking with him now!  Sorry, I didn't know how crappy Task Manager was, I know nada about windows...

Comment: I would time how long it takes on both systems and see if the reason is because its using more to get it down quicker then on windows.

Comment: Well, I don't have a great answer here.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to the Windows machine in question or any such machine, and the graphs I saw seemed hard to believe.  I'm going to have to chalk it up to "We don't properly understand Task Manager", but I'll update it if i get more information.